# Can’t rename indexed pages with /2-uncategorised/2018-19-05-56 by Redirect component

Tags: redirect

I’ve renamed all joomla articles with right name URL. But I can’t do it with Redirect Joomla Component. It doesn’t redirect all renamed files: https://mywebsite.com/2-uncategotised/2018-19-05-56 
Plugin is switched on, other pages are well redirected ( such as “mywebsite.com/home — mywebsite.com”
I have already fixed configuration file in “live_site” but it still doesn’t work.
All the articles I have released with “category blog” cause they are too much.
I have already tried htaccess file and it works, but I don’t want to edit at all so I need to use exactly Joomla component.
I can’t fix the problem, help me please